# Only TrueType fonts are supported. This is not a TrueType font Exception

Tags: c#-2.0, truetype

How to set such that fontdialog only uses TrueType fonts?
Is there any property?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/e50a3dc2-a9d9-4eea-aae6-39bc7c18b04e