# in C# winform, I got: "only truetype fonts are supported. This is not a TrueType Font"

Tags: c#, fonts, truetype

I have C# winform, I installed a couple of ttf fonts, but when i set the text box font to any of the ones i downloaded, i get this error Even though I'm 100% sure that the font I installed is ttf .. 
why ? and how to fix this ?

Comment: Are you sure that it is the act of setting the font, or is it the fact that there are other non-TTF that are there?  Just asking, because I see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302454/c-sharp-setting-fontdialog-to-only-display-truetype-fonts).

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's about setting the font.

Comment: You are having an argument with a machine.  You'll lose the argument.  Don't download fonts unless you used your credit card and can cancel your order.  And avoid OpenType fonts, they are not supported by Winforms.

Answer (score 60):

This happens when you install new fonts while Visual Studio is running. Close Visual Studio, and then reopen it. The problem will be solved.

Comment: While the marked answer provides this solution in a link, this answer distinctly details the solution

Answer (score 2):

After downloading the font, I simply double-clicked it and hit 'Install'.
However, this did not work, the font was not displayed in Win 10 *Font Settings*, besides that it was in the */Windows/Fonts/* folder.
Some programs did find the font (such as Gimp), others, like VS or even Win10 itself - did not find them. After a restart, the font was not shown again (until a new double-ckicl/install).

---

#### Solution: Right-click on the Font and select *'Install for all Users'*

Answer (score 2):

Have font with License "Source Sans Pro".
Installed and usable in every MS-Application.
For VS Forms-Project, i needed to "reinstall" it with

**Right-click on the Font and select 'Install for all Users'**

After VS restart, the misleading error vanished.

Answer (score 0):

Use nuget [WpfColorFontDialog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WpfColorFontDialog/) in the WPF projects instead, this supports OpenType fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    label1.Font = new Font("myFont", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
}
```