# Using an OpenType Font throws a FileNotFoundException was unhandled error

Tags: c#, fonts, opentype

I am required to use an OCR A font and normally don't have any problems with TrueType font files, but now that I'm using an otf (OpenType font) file I am getting this error when I try to add to my font collection using the following code:

```
        string ocrfont_file = (Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, @"OCRAStd.otf"));
        //string ocrfont_file = (Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, @"OCRAEXT.TTF"));
        fontCollection.AddFontFile(ocrfont_file);
```

Any way I can make this to work as desired?

Comment: Obviously your file is not found :). Check if you are using the right path to your file. Do a debug print of ocrfont_file for example... and you should use exception-handling when accessing your file.

Comment: GIYF
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551805/in-c-sharp-winform-i-got-only-truetype-fonts-are-supported-this-is-not-a-tru][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551805/in-c-sharp-winform-i-got-only-truetype-fonts-are-supported-this-is-not-a-tru

Comment: running through debugger as here's my text visualizer for ocrfont_file:  D:\devel\collect\ECitation\bin\Release\OCRAStd.otf

there is indeed an OCRAStd.otf in that folder, double-checked spelling/case, etc...

Comment: It turned out the OCR A Extended was acceptable after all but am still concerned that OpenType fonts are not supported.