# Winform font changes at runtime on deployed machine

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

I have my WinForms application with a custom font, the font is rendered correctly on my development machine but immediately I run it on the deployment machine, the font reverts to some default windows font, I think Tahoma.

I tried installing the fonts on the deployment machine but to no avail. Restarting didn't help either. It's a Windows 7 Machine. (POS Machine)

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: `I tried installing the fonts on the deployment machine` if it's there it should work. How did you installed the font? And how are you targeting it?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by targeting but I'm basically specifying the font on the control. As for installation, its a normal windows font install.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant specifying the font. Does the font show up in `character map`? (it's a windows application)

Comment: And maybe this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551805/in-c-sharp-winform-i-got-only-truetype-fonts-are-supported-this-is-not-a-tru

Comment: Yeah, fonts are showing in character map

Comment: And the possibly related link I send you, did that help?

Comment: Is the language/character set the same in the two machines and/or the application when deployed? If that font doesn't support a specific character set, the control will fall back to a font that supports the current language/character set.

Comment: About Font fall-back: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612395/7444103) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51451303/7444103)